# Using || OR in coldfusion if statement with isDefined

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I am using session variables in Coldfusion 2018 and I am trying to figure out how to add a variable with the way my if statements are set up.

```
<cfif isDefined("session")
            and structKeyExists(session, 'checkout')
                and structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'info')
                    and structKeyExists(session.checkout.info, 'andor_1') >
        <cfif session.checkout.info.andor_1 eq "And">
      <strong>- All signatures are required.</strong>
      </cfif>
      </cfif>

or 

<cfif isDefined("session")
            and structKeyExists(session, 'checkout')
                and structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'info')
                    and structKeyExists(session.checkout.info, 'bandor_1') >
        <cfif session.checkout.info.bandor_1 eq "And">
      <strong>- All signatures are required.</strong>
      </cfif>
      </cfif>
```

The if statements are almost identical `andor_1` or `bandor_1` but either one might not always exist which is why I am using the isDefined.

I have tried using `||` and `or`.

```
 <cfif isDefined("session")
                and structKeyExists(session, 'checkout')
                    and structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'info')
                        and structKeyExists(session.checkout.info, 'andor_1') 
|| isDefined("session")
                and structKeyExists(session, 'checkout')
                    and structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'info')
                        and structKeyExists(session.checkout.info, 'bandor_1')>
            <cfif session.checkout.info.andor_1 eq "And" || session.checkout.info.bandor_1 eq "And">
          <strong>- All signatures are required.</strong>
          </cfif>
          </cfif>
```

Any help combining these `cfifs` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: Coldfusion 2018

Comment: With CF2018, I'd definitely switch to cfscript syntax, since you're working on a modern version of CF. And for this I'd use the safe navigation operator. This is essentially the purpose of this operator. For `OR`, the `||` operator _can_ be used in a `cfif` tag, but it looks much less out of place in script.  :-)

Comment: I'd recommend considering the elvis ?: operator.  It saves a lot of hassle for deep nested structs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way in CF is 'OR' as opposed to ||.

However, in your first example you've place the "OR" outside of your IF statements.  Try this:

```
 <cfif isDefined("session") AND structKeyExists(session, 'checkout') AND structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'info')
                AND (
                        (structKeyExists(session.checkout.info, 'andor_1') AND session.checkout.info.andor_1 eq "And")
                        OR
                        (structKeyExists(session.checkout.info, 'bandor_1') AND session.checkout.info.bandor_1 eq "And")
                    )>

     <strong>- All signatures are required.</strong>
</cfif>
```

Comment: `||` will work in cfscript. CFTags are a little less flexible. But in CF2016+, Safe Navigation Operator can also be used in tags. `<cfif session?.checkout?.info?.andor_1 EQ "And" OR session?.checkout?.info?.bndor_1 EQ "And">.....</cfif>`

Comment: `||` is supported in ColdFusion since CF8 (including CFML).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using CF2016, you can use the Safe Navigation Operator, or `?.` (https://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/language-enhancements-cf-2016.html). And you should also start using cfscript for these kinds of logic things.

```
<cfscript>
// Setup my struct. Session is a struct. I renamed it for my example since it's a special word.
s = {
    checkout : {
        info : { 
            andor_1 : "And" , 
            bndor_1 : "And" 
        }
    }
} ;

//writeDump(session);

// If CF2016+ Safe Navigation Operator To The Rescue!

if( s?.checkout?.info?.andor_1 == "And" || s?.checkout?.info?.bndor_1 == "And" ) {
  writeOutput("<strong>- All signatures are required.</strong>");
}
</cfscript>
```

https://trycf.com/gist/a82b8466c427fb40b53bbc506e4d419d/lucee5?theme=monokai

Answer (score 2):

Another option (although less performant than using `structKeyExists()`.

```
<cfif isDefined("session.checkout.info.andor_1") AND session.checkout.info.andor_1 eq "And" 
  OR isDefined("session.checkout.info.bandor_1") AND session.checkout.info.andor_1 eq "And">

  <strong>- All signatures are required.</strong>
</cfif>
```

Something to look into would be setting some default values so that you don't need to run `isDefined` or `structKeyExists` checks. That has the potential to clean up your code quite a bit and make it more readable.

There are of course going to be exceptions or scenarios where they are necessary (e.g. consuming a response from an API).

Comment: Good call on the code reduction, but you can still use `StructKeyExists` instead of `IsDefined`.  You also owe me a beer for voting your reputation into triple digits.